# Improve text on Closed Questions on /help

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help

I learned today that [`/help`](https://stackoverflow.com/help) just launched for Stack Overflow.  I have a suggestion for an improvement to the copy on one of the subsections.

There's a heading that says `Question Closed` and below it:

[`I do not understand why this question was closed`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed). Its text reads:

> Stack Exchange is collaboratively built, maintained, and moderated by the community. If you >see a question and you disagree with the stated reason of its closure, you should:
>
> 1. Leave a comment to that effect on the question itself. Be detailed -
>      explain why the question shouldn't have been closed. Be constructive -
>      name-calling is as likely to drive folks away as it is win them to
>      your cause. Remember, anyone on the site with at least 3,000
>      reputation points can vote to re-open a question - even if a moderator
>      closed it.
> 2. Flag the question for moderator attention. Again, explain
>      why it should be re-openened. There is more than one moderator, and
>      moderators do reconsider their decisions.
> 3. If you have at least 3,000 reputation points, vote to re-open yourself.
>
> If you're  simply unsure about the validity of the closure, the best place to ask is on the community's meta site. Asking in the meta site allows those who took
>   the action to comment, and will help others to learn about the issues
>   being discussed. You can find a link to a site's meta in the top bar
>   of any of our sites.

The text itself is fine, for the most part.  One crucial thing it's missing is the ability of a user to take action themselves to improve the question.  I suggest adding text like:

> Closed questions are in a transient state.  If the question is improved, it can be re-opened. Since Stack Overflow is collaboratively built, you can suggest an edit to the question to improve it.  Once it's edited, flag it for re-opening.

This blurb could also go in front of the blurb for #2.  This is just a suggestion for possible text, the exact verbiage needs some work.

Comment: *"Closing doesn't mean the end of a question. If the question is improved, it can be re-opened."*

Comment: What is the suggesting an edit part about; can't the OP (regardless of reputation) edit their own question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Love the verbiage for your first comment. I'm not too sure on the correct verbiage for the `suggesting the edit` part because the way the current text reads, it could be referring to a third party seeing the closed question, and it could refer to the original poster viewing it.